# Why won't my table I created in one tablespace show up when I query it from another tablespace?

Tags: oracle11g

Both tablespaces are in the same DB so in Oracle SQL Developer, if I login to one tablespace tb1 i can see all the tables in tb2. Because of permissions I was unable to create the table tb2.new_table while logged into tb1. So I logged into tb2 and made tb2.new_table and can query it there. When I log back into tb1 I cannot see the newly created tb2.new_table. I'm just wondering why it's not showing up, I did commit after I made the new table.

My confusion comes as when I was logged into tb1 I was able to add a column to a table in tb2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't log in to a tablespace.  And you don't refer to a table by its tablespace (a table can exist in multiple tablespaces or in no tablespace).  If you are referring to a table `tb2.new_table`, that implies that `tb2` is the name of a schema, not a tablespace.  Tablespaces have nothing to do with permissions, they are simply a collection of physical data files.  Schemas do impact permissions.

It appears that you created a new table in schema2 but haven't given user1 permission to do anything with that table.  Assuming that is the case, as user2 run the commant

```
grant select on new_table to user1
```

and then user1 should be able to

```
select * from user2.new_table
```

If you want user1 to be able to insert, update, and/or delete data in `new_table`, you'd need to grant those permissions as well, i.e.

```
grant insert, update, delete on new_table to user1
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! That worked. I guess this came up as when I was on the development DB I didn't have to grant permissions to different users, but now that I'm on the testing one, it seems that I do.